# Does anyone know where I can find a simple version of the A* algorithm in php?

Tags: php, path-finding, a-star

Or version in a similar language. One that's for all types of maps not just 2d.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the types of maps you are hoping to solve? I guess 3D, but 3D as in game engine, or 3D as in movement in all axis?

Comment: All the examples I've found on google relate to pathfinding on a grid. I just need to navigate a network diagram which has a start point and an end point. Like this one where 10 is the start and 50 is the end:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Pert_chart_colored.gif

I was planning on modifying an a* algorithm to find the longest path. Is there a better algorithm for this?

Answer (score 1):

2d/3d isn't really relevant, any shortest route algorithm should be based on a straightforward network of nodes, not a 2-d or 3-d representation of such.
http://codezilla.com/projects/a-star/